# Keeping track of changes across many classes

Tags: c#, .net

I have a factory class that directs work across many different worker classes. Each one of these worker classes generates files. I'm trying to keep track of these files, so that at the end, assuming everything went well, I can deal with each of them. I've tried just passing around an instance of a tracker class, but it started to seem too coupled. I tried events but ran into a problem with worker classes instantiating classes of its own.  Should I just pass a reference through multiple levels of classes, or is there a pattern that addresses this type of issue?

Edit in response to Jakub:
I'm trying to handle files generated throughout the process. The files should get added to the FileTracker instance created by the factory, so that at the end, the factory can call the DoSomething method on the tracker. 
The problem I'm running into with events is that I'd want the event handler to be defined in the factory so that I don't have to implement a handler in Classes A - C. Especially since those classes are actually interfaces and could have any number of implementations themselves. This works until ClassC, which doesn't actually create files, so it wouldn't be raising events. Classes that it instantiates would be raising them, so ClassC would need to handle them. Unless of course there's some way to get the Factory class to handle events raised by classes it knows nothing about, but from what I understand there isn't.
The only way I can figure to make this work is to simply pass the trackerInstance as a parameter to every class.

Here's a quick code example: (I'm working with C# and .NET framework 4.7)

```
class FactoryWorker
{
    FileTracker trackerInstance = new FileTracker();
    ClassA a = new ClassA;
    a.MakeSomeFile();
    ClassB b = new ClassB;
    b.MakeSomeOtherFile();

    ClassC c = new ClassC;
    c.RunSplits();

    trackerInstance.DoSomethingWithAllFiles();
}

class ClassA
{
    void MakeSomeFile();
}

class ClassB
{
    void MakeSomeOtherFile();
}

class ClassC
{
    void RunSplits()
    {
        DataSplitA a = new DataSplitA();
        a.MakeSetOfFiles();
        DataSplitB b = new DataSplitB();
        b.MakeAnotherSetOfFiles();
    }
}

class DataSplitA
{
    void MakeSetOfFiles();
}

class DataSplitB
{
    void MakeAnotherSetOfFiles();
}

class FileTracker
{
    List<MadeFile> AllFilesMade {get; set;}
    void DoSomethingWithAllFiles();
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Where do you want to add the files? What was the problem with events? They should be the most obvious answer

Comment: How are you instantiating the classes A-C if they are supposed to be interfaces? You can make them abstract classes and subscribe to `Tracker`'s event in the constructor. Additionally you'd have to pass the `Tracker` to the constructor anyway unless you make it a singleton or somehow expose the functionality through static methods

Comment: I am not really clear on what you're trying to do here, but if your system is literally creating files on disk, and they're all going to a special folder, you can track all the files that are being added by using a [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) on the folder. From there you can create a list and do whatever you want to the files.